# RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop (PSD function in Python)

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool

I'm not sure if I uderstand the concept of multi-threading in Python. I want to call the function "plotpsd" twice, at the same time, so I do:

```
class Plotpsd: 
    def plotpsd(self, object):   
        samples = object.read_samples(1024)
        [Y,F]=psd(samples, NFFT=1024, Fs=2.4e6/1e6, Fc=43000000/1e6, noverlap=0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    devs= [object1, object2]
    pool = ThreadPool(4)
    p=Plotpsd()
    pool.map(p.plotpsd, devs)
    pool.close() 
    pool.join()
    object.close()
```

and I get this error:

> self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
>   RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Many GUI operations can only be called in main thread. Do time-consuming non-GUI things in a separate thread but the actual GUI things in main thread.

Comment: thank you. So by GUI operations you mean the PSD function? I need that operation to be performed in parallel.

Comment: I guess so. The full stack trace of the error should show which chain of calls caused the error.

Comment: thanks a lot! Yes, it was the PSD function, so I obtained the PSD function step by step (using the FFT, absolute value, etc) instead of directly using the PSD and it works now :)